# Display name of driver and amount of shifts they worked

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select dr_drvname, count(sh_wkflag)
from driver join shift on dr_drvnum = sh_drvnum
where sh_wkflag like '%T%'
group by dr_drvnum;
```

"T" means true for working that shift. How do I use count and draw names from another table?

Driver table contains all the names. Shift table contains the sh_wkflag which has the value of T or F depending on if the shift has been worked or not. I want to be able to get all the values of "T" and count it. Display the number of "T" grouped by the driver number from the driver table, along with the driver name which is in the driver table as well.

The query runs as long as i dont display the driver name, but i need to display the name as well. The Error i get is, dr_drvname is not a group by expression.

Comment: We would need to know the name and layout of the other table if we're to help you.

Comment: Edited to add further detail on the question

Comment: If that code that you posted works, what code do you have that does not work?  Post that, and tell us what doesn't work.  Does it give an error message?  Do you get no results from the query?  You have to tell us details.  We can't guess at what's going wrong.

Comment: it works if i take dr_drvname out i want to get it to work while keeping dr_drvname in. @AndyLester

Comment: What I'm saying is to please post the *exact code* that doesn't work.  Don't describe it, show it.  Then tell us the exact error that you get.

Comment: @AndyLester the code posted is the exact code that does not work. The error is dr_drvname is not a group by expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!  The error tells all.  Add `dr_drvname` to the `GROUP BY` clause.  It's redundant to grouping by `dr_drvnum`, but that's OK.

```
select dr_drvname, count(sh_wkflag)
from driver join shift on dr_drvnum = sh_drvnum
where sh_wkflag like '%T%'
group by dr_drvnum, dr_drvname;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been looking at this thing for hours trying to figure it out. With this i can figure out further problems as well thanks!